# Do I need to Stop Sharepoint to use Windows Server Full Backup?

Tags: backup, windows-server

I think my question says it all.

I want to do a full server backup of the entire machine (Windows Server 2008) using the OS's built in "Windows Server Backup".  My server runs the SQL for Sharepoint and is also the domain controller.

Do I need to stop Sharepoint Services first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need to stop the any services on the server.

We took the backup of our OS & Drives every day. We never stop our SharePoint as our it is working 24/7.

Sometimes(very rare) performance goes down other wise no issue.

Comment: That is what I thought, too.  Thank you very much for a timely answer from someone who has done it already.  That's exactly why I posted my question here.

Comment: Have you ever tried to restore one of those backups made whilst everything is running?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've already accepted the answer from the fellow who answered me when I asked the question.  But I want to add my own answer here, too, to report my experience.

No, you don't have to stop Sharepoint.

I took a Windows Server (2008) backup with Sharepoint running using the "full" "bare metal" option.  I put the backup on a network folder.  Then I hooked up an old Optiplex I had lying around and booted it with the Windows Server 2008 installation CD.  I used the options for restoring the full backup.  Everything went very well.

Active Directory was all there (I made sure this machine was not online when I booted it after the restore!), DNS was there, Sharepoint was there - I could navigate all the pages just fine.  Of course, the drivers were mismatched, and my Optiplex didn't have the same resources as the PowerEdge R610, but it was all there and it all worked, at least in my cursory check.  I noted that the most recently created pages were also present - anything that was made before the backup began was all there.

So, in conclusion, yes you can make a Windows Server Backup whilst Sharepoint is running, and I've done it.